# When I click on the element parent of the dropdown menu, click the one child below

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, prestashop

When i click on my parent element on the dropdown menu, the latter click on his child.

I don't know what is the problem, but you can find it by clicking on this following link and switch the viewport to mobile with the inspector: 
[www.backlabel.com](http://www.backlabel.com)

Click on the "Collection" and then click on the "Fabric", this select the child "Eucalyptus" of his parent "Fabric".

**HTML**

```
<!--HERE THE COLLECTIONS-->
<div id="megamenu" class="vel-megamenu clearfix vel-megamenu-active">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav  menu level1">
<li class="item  parent group"><a href="#" title="COLLECTIONS">COLLECTIONS</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/47-forward" title="Forward">Forward</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/48-dreamy" title="Dreamy">Dreamy</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/46-nourishing-essentials" title="Nourishing Essentials">Nourishing Essentials</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>



<!--HERE THE FABRICS-->

<li class="item  parent group"><a href="#" title="FABRICS">FABRICS</a><div class="dropdown-menu"><ul><li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics" title="View All">View All</a></li>
<li class="item  parent group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/46-nourishing-essentials" title="Nourishing Essentials">Nourishing Essentials</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/21-bamboo-silk-fibre" title="Bamboo &amp; Silk Fibre">Bamboo &amp; Silk Fibre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/24-eucalyptus" title="Eucalyptus Fibre">Eucalyptus Fibre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/25-milk-protein-fibre" title="Milk Protein Fibre">Milk Protein Fibre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#seaweed" title="Seaweed FIbre">Seaweed FIbre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/59-sea-island-fibre" title="Sea Island Fibre">Sea Island Fibre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#organic-cotton" title="Organic Cotton Fibre">Organic Cotton Fibre</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#egyptian-cotton" title="Egyptian Cotton Fibre">Egyptian Cotton Fibre</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item  parent group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/48-dreamy" title="Dreamy">Dreamy</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#belize-cotton-cashmere" title="Belize Cotton &amp; Cashmere">Belize Cotton &amp; Cashmere</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#jaipur-cashmere" title="Jaipur Cashmere">Jaipur Cashmere</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/content/11-fabrics#cashmere" title="Cariaggi Cashmere">Cariaggi Cashmere</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item  parent group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/47-forward" title="Forward">Forward</a><div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/86-performance-cotton" title="Performance Cotton">Performance Cotton</a></li>
<li class="item  group"><a href="http://www.backlabel.com/58-japanese-fleece" title="Japanese Fleece">Japanese Fleece</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vel-megamenu .menu {
float: inherit!Important;
}

.navbar-nav {
margin: 10.25px -10px;
}

.nav {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.vel-megamenu .navbar-nav li {
float: none;
clear: both;
position: relative !important;
border: solid 2px;
}

.vel-megamenu .nav > li {
position: initial;
}

.nav > li {
position: relative;
display: block; 
}

.header2 #vel-megamenu #megamenu {
display: inline-block;
}


.vel-megamenu-active {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
background-color: #474747;
}

.vel-megamenu {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
bottom: 0px;
/* width: 280px; */
width: 333px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 999999;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
```

Comment: Post your code *here* and describe the specific problem more in detail so we can help you

Comment: Welcome to SO ... Linking just to your page will make this question useless, in order to make it valid for SO and future users post some code here and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok i did it, please let me know asap :)

Comment: @DaniP have no idea? :(